# read more script cuts at html tags

Tags: php

I have a php code that chops the string and places a read more button. This all worked well until I saw it chops trough some html tags in the text. Witch ruins the functionality. This is my code:

```
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

function chopstring( $string, $id, $maxlength = 480, $append = '...' ){
$strlen = strlen( $string );
if( $strlen <= (int) $maxlength ){
    return $string;
}
else{
    $chopped = substr( $string, 0, (int) $maxlength );
    $chopped_on_space = substr( $chopped, 0, strrpos( $chopped, ' ' ) );
    return ( $chopped_on_space ) . $append . " <a class='btn-orange right' href='".$self."?id=".$id."'>Lees verder</a>";
    }
}
```

how can i make sure this doesn't chop trough br img and url tags anymore

Comment: The best way is to probably use `strip_tags` to remove HTML. You could parse it but it could get pretty complex.

Comment: this is probably a close to impossible endeavor without stripping tags. While you could do something like chop after N characters and backup if there is half an open html tag. You would likely end up with open tags that don't get closed like a `<div>` or a `<li>` that end up breaking your website layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helped:

```
function chopstring( $string, $id, $maxlength = 480 ){
    $strlen = strlen( $string );
    if( $strlen <= (int) $maxlength ){
        return $string;
    }
    else{
        $chopped = substr( $string, 0, (int) $maxlength );
        $chopped_on_space = substr( $chopped, 0, strrpos( $chopped, ' ' ) );
        $output = new tidy;
        $output->parseString($chopped_on_space, array('show-body-only'=>true, 'indent'=>true), 'UTF8');
        $output->repairString();
        $output = preg_replace('#(( ){0,}<br( {0,})(/{0,1})>){1,}$#i', '', $output);
        return ( $output ) . "... <a class='btn-orange right' href='".$self."?id=".$id."'>Lees verder</a>";
        }
}
```

the $output grabs the $chopped_on_space and gets a repair and the preg_replace makes sure there will be no `<br>` at the end of the string.